# Only first elif statement triggering

Tags: python

This code below works as intended for the `if` and first `elif` statement. But if I try and trigger the statements below Python doesn't return anything at all, not even an error code.

```
score = input ('Please enter your score: ')
try : 
    fscore = float (score)
except :
    print ('Error, please enter a number')
    quit ()
if fscore < 0.60 :
    print ('F')
elif fscore >= 0.60 :
    if fscore < 0.70 :
        print ('D')
elif fscore >= 0.70 :
    if fscore < 0.80 :
        print ('C')
elif fscore >= 0.80 :
    if fscore < 0.90 :
        print ('B')
elif fscore >= 0.90 :
    if fscore <= 1.00 :
        print ('A')
else :
    print ('Error')
```

Tried entering a number >= 0.70 expecting Python to print. Instead Python returned nothing, not even an error.

Comment: In that case `elif fscore >= 0.60` will be executed and inside that block `if fscore < 0.70` will not be executed. That is why nothing is printed

Comment: Add more `print`s so you can follow what happens. Or step through with a debugger to the same end.

Comment: if/elif chains are exclusive and *tested* in order, here if  the first branch (`fscore < 0.60`) fails the second (`fscore >= 0.60`) necessarily succeeds, thus is taken, and the other branches are not even considered. Testing more inside the branch does not make it back out, you need to perform complete range tests in the original condition.

Comment: ahh of course i feel like an idiot, thankyou kuro

Comment: Try `elif 0.60 <= fscore < 0.70: print('D') ; elif 0.70 <= fscore < 0.80: print('C')`

Answer (score 1):

Just after verifying if the number is inferior to 0.60 you check if is superior or equal to 0.60 and because is a elif the other elif will be skip because is already enter in one condition.

Comment: this is more of a comment than an answer, because you don't offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing can be handled using "table driven" code. By carefully constructing the "driver" (a dictionary in this case) we only need one *if* statement.

The key benefit here is that if the grading ranges change, then you just edit the dictionary - i.e., no more cumbersome *if/elif/else* constructs.

```
from operator import le, lt

GRADES = {
    0.6: (lt, "F"),
    0.7: (lt, "D"),
    0.8: (lt, "C"),
    0.9: (lt, "B"),
    1.0: (le, "A"),
}

score = float(input("Please enter your score: "))

for k, (f, g) in GRADES.items():
    if f(score, k):
        print(g)
        break
else:
    print("Error")
```